# Stopping another program from taking focus

Tags: windows, windows-7, focus, window-management

I need to run a lengthy set of unit tests quite often each day, and as part of the tests, some windows pop up and are subsequently closed by the test script. Ideally, I'd like to continue working while the tests are running, so I'd need to stop the testing software from taking focus or opening a window in front of what I'm currently working on.

Is there a way to stop descendants of a certain process from taking focus when opening a window and from opening a window at the top of the z-order, or can I redirect the windows to another screen where they don't bother me?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another user account, run your tests in your current user account, and just switch to another user account to do what you want.
But if you have a PC with low GH and RAM then I don't recommend you do that.